# How many operating systems are allowed to install a single computer?

Tags: operating-systems

I have already install windows 7 and ubuntu in my pc, but now I want to install windows server 2012 in same computer. Is it possible?

Comment: As many as you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install as many you want but, before to try to install X systems you should have some things in mind.

1. **[CPU Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CPU_architectures)**: If you want to install an operating system
   you must to be sure if that operating systems runs with your CPU.
2. **Minimun RAM Requirement**: The Minimun Amount of Memory used to run
   the operating system.
3. **Hard Disk Size**: You must to be sure you have enough space in your
   hard disk to install the Operating System.
4. **Graphics**: The minimum Specs of the
   Video Card to run the selected operating system.
5. [**MBR**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record)/[**GPT**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table): Master Boot Record / GUID Partition Table Limits.

Keep this in mind as minimun.

Comment: processor : intel core i7, Ram: 4gb, Hard disk: 1000gb, graphics: 4gb. So, I hope that I can install windows server 2012 without any hesitation. But, I want to know the process about install OS alongside other two OS. When I installed ubuntu then their was an option install ubuntu alongside windows 7 but when I will go to install another I don't know how do it.

Comment: @ikbal_ahmed ive answered this question 'How many operating systems are allowed to install a single computer?' try to find your answer here http://superuser.com/search or do a new one here http://superuser.com/questions/ask or edit your current one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no inherent limit to the number of operating systems that can be installed on a computer.

Issues you may encounter installing many operating systems include a limit on hard drive partitions and overwhelming your bootloader. Most people rarely have to worry about these issues.

Comment: What exactly is *overwhelming your bootloader*?

Comment: I have never see it happen, but older bootloaders couldn't have too many entries. It usually was only encountered by people hacking on the Linux kernel and creating a huge amount of bootable kernel versions without deleting the old ones.

Comment: @ztk that seems like an issue that was caused by the limited resources available to computers a while ago. I'd imagine that most current bootloaders can handle it fine.

Comment: I would agree that it isn't a likely problem with modern computers, but I was trying to think of possible limitations on the number of OS's